# Show only own record to Google Spreadsheet user and hide data from other users

Tags: google-sheets

I'm organizing an event, so I set up a table for people to sign up using [Google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/).

For concern of personal information privacy, I'd like to make it only be able to add a new record, for the new comers, while they are not permitted to view the other records.

If possible, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Google Form](http://forms.google.com) to collect the data.   It will let you, but not regular respondents, see the data.